# How to get the corresponding DataSet row number after filtering a BindingSource

Tags: c#, ms-access, binding

Basically I'm filtering through a `BindingSource` by input from a `TextBox`. I'm doing this by doing the following :-

```
  //Filter Results
        bindingSource.Filter = "Term1 = '" + textBox1.Text + "'" + "AND Term2='" + textBox2.Text + "'";


        loc = bindingSource.Find("term2", textBox2.Text);


        BindingSource.Position = loc;
```

However if I now wish to update the corresponding record in the `DataSet` by using the BindingSource.Position as an indication to the current row it updates the incorrect row in the data set. I have a feeling that this is down to the fact that I've filter results down in the binding source so there's going to be a mismatch.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the `BindingSource.Current` should give you a reference to the row its bound to. But you shouldn't need to do this since the row should already be updated.

Comment: Thought as much, my problem was I was missing BindingSource.EndEdit();